# MongoDB large collection slow search

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have large mongodb collection(5.3 million entries), each entry has list-field and some additional fields. For example:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518d51c808beda0b70cffffa"), 
  "a" : [ 0.00037, 0.00009 ], 
  "b" : "Some long str", 
  "c" : [ "element1", "element2", "element3" ] 
}
```

I have index on field `c` and I want to make search on it. Moreover I want to search by all permutations of this list, for example I want object above to be in search result for query `"c": ["element3", "element2", "element1"]`.

I use pymongo this way:

```
from itertools import permutations
...
query = ['element1', 'element2', 'element3']
query_permutations = list(permutations(query, len(query)))
results = collection.find({"c": {"$in": query_permutations}}).sort("a", -1)
```

Is there any way to make it faster?

**UPD:** explain() on smaller version of collection:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 11053,
    "nscannedObjects" : 11053,
    "nscanned" : 11053,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 11053,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 11053,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 41,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "server" : "machine.local:27017"
}
```

Comment: Can you give us an explain()? Also what are the indexes on the collection?

Comment: Yea that query is using no indexes, you might wanna add `{c:1,a:-1}` or if the mongo optimiser will see it `{a:-1,c:1}` but I am unsure if the optimiser will see that latter index but it will make a cardinally sorted $in range

Comment: @Sammaye there is an error `cannot index parallel arrays [c] [a]`

Comment: `a` is of type array? edit: stupid me I didn't look at the doc structure at the top of the question

Comment: @Sammaye as in example, yes.

Comment: I am unsure how useful sorting on `a` will be here, what are you hoping to accomplish?

Comment: @Sammaye the main goal is to sort by `a[0]`. Looks like sorting here is some legacy code, because before `a` was just float.

Comment: Hmm you might wanna factor that figure out of `a`. I am trying to remember how MongoDB will sort this unfortunately I do not have a copy of MongoDB to actually test this on the machine I am on atm. I think the best bet atm is factor the figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Compound multikey indexes may only include one array field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-multi-key). Your fields *a* and *c* are both arrays and you cannot create index *{c:1,a:-1}*, but you can create index *{c:1}*:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({c: 1})
```

Also, consider using the operator *[$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/#op._S_all)* in your query, then you'd kill the need to create a permutation of the elements on field *c*. However, if you replace *[$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/#op._S_in)* by *[$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/#op._S_all)*, the query'd return elements with documents that have other elements unspecified in the query:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("518d51c808beda0b70cffffa"),
  "a" : [ 0.00037, 0.00009 ],
  "b" : "Some long str",
  "c" : [ "element1", "element2", "element3", "element4" ]
}
```

To prevent that, you can combine the operator *[$all](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/#op._S_all)* with the operator *[$size](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/size/#op._S_size)*:

```python
results = collection.find({"c": {"$all": query, "$size": len(query)}}).sort("a", -1)
```

### EDIT:

As @Sammaye stated, you have a third choice about the compound index. You can redesign your schema and break down the *a* field into more fields, but you need to ask yourself *what* type of sorting you want to perform in this query.

Comment: I think $in is the operator he is looking for, I have no idea what part of the question made you pull out $all, also only an index on c would not be optimal since it would create a scanandorder case

Comment: @Sammaye, it's not possible to create a compound index with more than one array field, so he has two choices. He can use an index to scan or no index at all.

Comment: @Sammaye, he _wants_ _to_ _search_ _by_ _all_ _permutations_ of the list, so he is only creating a giant query to use _$in_.

Comment: He has a third choice, schema alteration. Such a change would be better than considering a scanandorder in this case. Also that English sounds more like he wants to scan documents by all permutations in the list, it doesn't mean that the document needs to contain "all" permutations

Comment: One more thing is *how* he wants to search, sorting on a subdocument may not provide the sort he is *actually* looking for (`a[0]`), i.e. I am also not sure why you are suggesting sorting on a multikey field to be a good idea

Comment: Okay @Sammaye, I agree with you about redesign the schema, but I still disagree on the permutation thing. If he wants all permutations, he wants an array that has _$all_ elements (but no more) from the list, in any order. The results don't differ at all.

Comment: @Sammaye, your argument about _sort_ is also a good remark. I just answered the question without wonder **what** the OP really want to.